# Make image link appear on hover without using JavaScript

Tags: html, css

I have a DIV that's wrapped in an anchor tag; all of the DIV is clickable, even the whitespace that doesn't contain any text (and this is desired, for my purposes).

I have another anchor tag that's absolutely positioned over this DIV with a higher z-index.  This anchor tag wraps an image (a "close" icon).

This all works correctly, EXCEPT that I only want the close icon to appear on hover.  As currently implemented, the close icon is always visible.  I'm not sure if I'm going about this the right way.  As a further wrinkle, I need to implement this without using JavaScript, since I'm running on an embedded system and I can't afford to invoke a JavaScript engine.

This only needs to work with WebKit (even more specifically, it only needs to work with Chrome).

Can someone give me a nudge in the right direction?

Here's the CSS I'm using:

```
.content {
    border-top: 1px solid #eff1f2;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #c5c5c5;
    padding: 8px 11px;
    border-left: 1px solid #c5c5c5;
}

div.content:hover {
    background-color: #d1d6de;
}

.close {
    position: absolute;
    right: 100px;
    top: 10px;
    z-index: 0;
}
```

Here's my HTML:

```
<div>
    <a href="native://action1/">
        <div class="content">
            <p>This is my content</p>
        </div>
    </a>
        <a href="native://action2/">
            <img class="close" src="images/close.png"/>
        </a>
</div>
```

[Here's a jsFiddle that contains my source](http://jsfiddle.net/C5Y36/4/).

Comment: Not that it makes a difference, but `div` inside `a` is invalid. Use `span` instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All you need, given your current HTML, is a simple revision of your CSS:

```
.close {
    display: none; /* Added this to hide the element */
    /* other CSS */
}

​div:hover a .close { /* to make the element visible while hovering the parent div */
    display: block;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/C5Y36/8/).

With the use of the CSS transition properties, you can also use fade in/fade out:

```
.close {
    opacity: 0; /* to hide the element */
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s linear;
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.5s linear;
    -ms-transition: opacity 0.5s linear;
    -o-transition: opacity 0.5s linear;
    transition: opacity 0.5s linear;
    /* other CSS */
}

div:hover a .close {
    opacity: 1; /* to reveal the element */
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s linear;
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.5s linear;
    -ms-transition: opacity 0.5s linear;
    -o-transition: opacity 0.5s linear;
    transition: opacity 0.5s linear;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/C5Y36/10/).

---

It's also worth noting that, prior to HTML 5, it's invalid to wrap a block-level element inside of an inline-level, the `a`, element. In HTML 5, though, this seems to be valid (though I've yet to find the W3 documentation to support this).

Comment: Perfect!  The transition properties are nice too; I wasn't familiar with those.  I do have concerns with wrapping the DIV in an anchor tag, but as you noted, it does appear to work.  Is there a less fragile approach I should take?

Comment: That depends entirely on why you chose to wrap the element in an `a` to start with. But it's worth noting that `p` is *also* a block-level tag, and so is equally (outside of HTML5) problematic.